# How to Keep RecyclerView's Buttons Clicked Respectfully - Android

Tags: android, android-button, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that is populated with CardViews. On each of the CardViews there is a button, which up votes the post.

Here is what the button looks when it is not pressed,

[image: up vote - not pressed]

Here is what the button looks when it is pressed,

[image: up vote - pressed]

My code works for achieving this but I have a problem since it is a RecyclerView. When I scroll down the posts the RecyclerView recycles the previous posts that have been up voted. So a post will show that it was up voted even though a user never up voted it.

How can I keep the buttons pressed respectfully for each CardView?

**This is my Adapter**

```
public class DiscoverRecyclerAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscoverRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    Typeface customFont;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTitle;
        public TextView mVoterCounter;
        public ImageButton mVoterButton;
        public ViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.CardView v) {
            super(v);
            mTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mVoterCounter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.voter_counter);

            //Initialize voter button
            mVoterButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.voter);

            mVoterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mVoterButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_voter_pressed);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public DiscoverRecyclerAdapter(String[] myDataset, Typeface passedFont) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        customFont = passedFont;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public DiscoverRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_discover, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new ViewHolder((android.support.v7.widget.CardView)v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitle.setText(mDataset[position]);
        holder.mTitle.setTypeface(customFont);
        holder.mVoterCounter.setTypeface(customFont);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

along with mDataset you will also need a boolean array say mIsSelected
now size of this will be equal to size of array mDataSet or create class if you want.

Then in onBindViewHolder do as

```
 if(mIsSelected[position]
  mVoterButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_voter_pressed);
else
 mVoterButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_voter_unpressed);
```

and move button onclick inside onBindViewHolder as below

```
 holder.mVoterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              mVoterButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_voter_pressed);
              mIsSelected[position] = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This approach worked for me. I am not sure how well it will work when I retrieve the data from a database but for hard coding the boolean array it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the previous rows view of all previous data at the beginning of the onBindViewHolder.

In your case it seems you need to clear all the visibility params of the view components to whatever you deem to be the default. After that go ahead and populate the card with the data.

Being that your passed in dataset is only a string you will need to either make a call to your own API to get the up-vote count / status. Or change  your dataset to a custom object array that tracks all of the different components you need to setup and record the data of each card.

In short: As the views get recycled you need to clean them up before re-use.